# What does .collect() do?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I understand that `.collect(pf)`, where `pf` is a partial function, is the equivalent to `.filter(pf.isDefinedAt _).map(pf)`. What I don't understand is what just `.collect()` does. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Wait, what?! Why this question is marked a "off topic" with suggestion that it should go to Server Fault?! It's a complete nonsense!

Comment: And yes, it's maybe "zero effort before question" question. But still, it may deserve downvotes, but not closing as off topic and redirection to Server Fault

Comment: I think the guy is confused between the scala collect and spark's rdd.collect. I don't think people will be willing to answer that on Server Fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`collect` without parameters [fetches all data stored in a RDD to the driver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

> Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.
>
> Note
>
> This method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.

There is no connection to the version with `PartialFunction` whatsoever. Both are used for completely different things.